# Flutter SQLite get value between 2 dates, one is dynamic ( flutter Moor )

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart, dart-pub, flutter-moor

I am building a finance app, created a table called wallets, the wallets table has a column called `startDate`. using ( flutter_moor ) package for SQLite

Now I need to only retrieve the latest created wallet and only if is in the range of 30 days since it been created using the value of the above field `startDate`, which means on the new month I can not get it

My Code:

```dart
Stream<Wallet> watchLatestCreatedWallet() {
  final Stream<Wallet> wallet = (
    select(wallets)
    ..orderBy([
      (wallet) => OrderingTerm(
        expression: wallet.startDate,
        mode: OrderingMode.desc
      ) 
    ])
    // somthing wrong I did, obviously always will return true
    // ..where((tbl) => tbl.startDate.isBetween(tbl.startDate, tbl.startDate + Duration(days: 30) ) )
    ..limit(1)
  )
  .watchSingle();

  return wallet;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by

```dart
Stream<Wallet> watchLatestCreatedWallet() {
  final endRange = DateTime.now();
  final startRange = endRange.subtract(Duration(days: 30));
  final Stream<Wallet> wallet = (
    select(wallets)
    ..orderBy([
      (wallet) => OrderingTerm(
        expression: wallet.startDate,
        mode: OrderingMode.desc
      ) 
    ])
    ..where((tbl) => tbl.startDate.isBetween(startRange, endRange ) )
    ..limit(1)
  )
  .watchSingle();

  return wallet;
}
```